# useEffect is on a infinity loop even with an empty dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, use-effect, redux-toolkit

I dispatching a function using my useEffect to populate my state when the page is mounted. The useEffect is on a infinity loop, even if i put an empty dependency array.

```
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("xibo"));
  const access_token = token.access_token;

  useEffect(() => {
    
      dispatch(getDisplays(access_token));
      
  }, []);
```

I already try to put some dependencies but with the same result.

```
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("xibo"));
  const access_token = token.access_token;

  useEffect(() => {
    
      dispatch(getDisplays(access_token));
    
  }, [access_token, dispatch]);
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

this is the full code of the file

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { WaveLoading } from "react-loadingg";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getDisplays } from "../features/xiboAuth/xiboSlice";

const DisplayList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isLoading } = useSelector((store) => store.xibo);

  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("xibo"));
  const access_token = token.access_token;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getDisplays(access_token));
  }, [access_token, dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <WaveLoading />
      ) : (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="title_table">
            <h3>List of displays</h3>
          </div>
          <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th className="col">#</th>
                <th className="col">name</th>
                <th className="col">type</th>
                <th className="col">ip</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default DisplayList;
```

this is the file that call this component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { WaveLoading } from "react-loadingg";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import DisplayList from "../components/DisplayList";
import { getDisplays, getToken } from "../features/xiboAuth/xiboSlice";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { user } = useSelector((store) => store.auth);
  const { isError, message, isLoading, xibo } = useSelector(
    (store) => store.xibo,
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      toast.error(message);
    }
    if (user) {
      dispatch(getToken());
    }
  }, [user, isError, message, dispatch]);


  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <WaveLoading />
      ) : (
        <div className="col py-3">
          <div className="d-flex dash_dsp_list">
            <DisplayList />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

and this is the reducer that the useEffect must call only once.

```
  import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
  import xiboService from "./xiboService.js";

  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("xibo"));

  const initialState = {
    xibo: data ? data : null,
    displays: null,
    isError: false,
    isLoading: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    message: "",
  };

  export const getToken = createAsyncThunk("xibo/getToken", async (thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await xiboService.getAccessToken();

      if (response.data.status === 201) {
        localStorage.setItem("xibo", JSON.stringify(response.data.data));
      }

      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();

      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  });

  export const getDisplays = createAsyncThunk(
    "xibo/getDisplays",
    async (data, thunkAPI) => {
      try {
        return await xiboService.getDisplayList(data);
      } catch (error) {
        const message =
          (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString();

        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
      }
    },
  );

  export const xiboSlice = createSlice({
    name: "xibo",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      reset: (state) => {
        state.isError = false;
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.message = "";
      },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder
        .addCase(getToken.pending, (state) => {
          state.isLoading = true;
        })
        .addCase(getToken.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.isLoading = false;
          state.isSuccess = true;
          state.xibo = action.payload;
        })
        .addCase(getToken.rejected, (state, action) => {
          state.isLoading = false;
          state.isError = true;
          state.message = action.payload;
          state.xibo = null;
        })
        .addCase(getDisplays.pending, (state) => {
          state.isLoading = true;
        })
        .addCase(getDisplays.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.isLoading = false;
          state.isSuccess = true;
          state.displays = action.payload;
        })
        .addCase(getDisplays.rejected, (state, action) => {
          state.isLoading = false;
          state.isError = true;
          state.message = action.payload;
          state.displays = null;
        });
    },
  });

  export const { reset } = xiboSlice.actions;
  export default xiboSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example you said that your `useEffect` fires repeatedly even with an empty dependency array. What this means is that your `DisplayList` component is being recreated continuously. Obviously the issue is in your `Dashboard` component and it would have to be something in the `useEffect`.